# Disable scroll in a iframe

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have my html page with a iframe, and when I put the mouse on the iframe and I use the mouse scroll button it will scroll the iframe page and I don't want that to happen. But I don't want the scroll to be totaly disable in this iframe because I have a fresque and I must be abble to zoom in with the scroll

How could I do ?

I have try to do `scrollTo(0, 0);` but it does it on the real page and not on the iframe.

Comment: "I want to disable the scroll of the page without disabeling the scroll." - wat?

Comment: well I want that when people use scroll button it doesn't scroll the iframe page. But without disable scroll because I need that the button scroll works for a zoom on a fresque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the `mousewheel` event to cancel the scroll.

Example code:

```
window.onload=function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ //just to be sure that the document exists
        document.onmousewheel=function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            //add here your code to zoom

        };
    },300);
};
```

Notice that IE8 will always "internally" use `event.preventDefault();` and the scroll won't work if you want to use a flag to enable/disable the scroll.

You can read more information here: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html

---

This is my old solution:

The question isn't specific enough, but I think I understood it.

Here is a piece of jQuery to fix what I understood:

```
(function($){
    $(function(){
        $(window).click(function(event){
            if(event.which==3) //middle button
            {
                event.preventDefault();
                //remaining code for the zoom(?)
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This should disable using the scroll wheel to scroll the page (doesn't work on touch).

You can include the code for the zooming(?) inside the `if` block.

Include this code **inside** the iframe!

Comment: Thanks that's it. I can't use jQuery but it should be ok

Comment: @leykan Let me fix it for you then.

Comment: @leykan I found a problem on my answer. You should remove the mark. I will try to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Try using the scrolling="no" option, as in

```
<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://www.google.com" width="400px" height="300"></iframe>
```

Comment: i can't the scroll will be disable at all and I need it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve then. Can you provide some more info?

Comment: Well I have my html page with a iframe, and when I put the mouse on the iframe and i use the mouse scroll button it will scroll the iframe page and I don't want that to happen. But I don't want the scroll to be totaly disable in this iframe because I have a fresque and I must be abble to zoom in with the scroll

Comment: So you want the iframe not to get the focus of the scroll and pass on the event to its container? You might be able to do that by capturing the mouse wheel event on the iframe and passing it on to the containing document.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming: "I want to disable the scroll of the page without disabeling the scroll **(in the `iframe`)**"

First, this CSS will turn off scrollbars on the page ...

```
<style type="text/css">
  html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
</style>
```

... and, this will disable scrolling anytime it is tried ...

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    scroll(0,0);
});
```

... although, this might be a better option ...

```
document.body.scroll = "no";
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
document.height = window.innerHeight;
```